# Post process windows video output

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glsl, fullscreen

I'm try to see if/how it is possible to make a windows(or even mac/linux for that matter) application that will post process everything that is on the screen. If possible I would like to be able to use glsl shaders to perform things like color inversion and sobel filtering to everything on screen. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Since you are discussing doing this portably, I think you will want to consider the way surfaces are handled in many window managers. In a compositing window manger (most new ones fall under this category), when the front/back buffers are swapped, the window manager uses a copy of the back buffer surface to do fancy 3D effects with using traditional APIs like OpenGL or D3D. Unfortunately, in Windows the DWM does not expose the surfaces that it uses directly, the best you can do with the public APIs are to get thumbnails for an arbitrary window blitted into your application.

Comment: There are some undocumented DWM API calls that may help you, namely `UpdateWindowShared (...)` and `GetSharedSurface (...)`. I know of at least one commercial product that actually uses these, and you may find some examples online of people who have successfully used this undocumented part of the API but the major problem is that you will wind up with a D3D surface, interop. will probably make doing this in OpenGL difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The [Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/) compositor for linux looks like it can do what you want. It includes many post processing effects already (as included plugins) and allows you to add your own through custom plugins. It looks like these plugins can use GLSL pixel shaders.

According to [this site](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/tweaksthings-to-do-after-install-of.html), the following commands should set up the CompizConfig Settings Manager on Ubuntu 13.04

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

Hopefully this provides a helpful starting point for your project!

**Disclaimer:** I have not actually used Compiz. I'm basing my description off of what I can find online.